# Python Selenium Beta Chrome driver uses wrong binary path

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently switching from chrome 102 to 104 Beta (since 103 has an unfixed error for my use case with a python - selenium script)

I installed the Chrome Beta 104 + the 104 chrome driver.
When I start up the script it recognizes that it's a 104 driver but the driver itself searches for the chrome.exe application within the old chrome path:

Where it searches right now:
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Where it should search for:
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chrome.exe

Is there some simple way of changing the binary path where the beta chrome driver searches for the exe? Something simple I could put within my python script would be lovely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that case, you should specify where selenium has to look to find your chrome executer with binary_location inside the Options class.

Try this one out:

Assuming your chromedriver.exe and python file are on the same folder, otherwise you'll have to specify the path of the chromedriver.exe as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chrome.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, service = Service("chromedriver.exe"))

browser.get(your_url)
```

Comment: Thx so much dude. But there seems to by a typo before the path you wrote: "r".

Comment: That's called an Rstring, preceding a string which treat backslashs as normals caracters, thus, making it better when working with file paths.

Comment: Ah good to know. Sorry I'm a noob haha.

Comment: @MikaCammann don't be, we're all here to learn something